# HTTP Error 414 not showing in Apache2 access log

Tags: http, apache2

Apache2 does not log `414 Request-URI Too Long` in access or error log, why and how to enable it?

Comment: Check the `LogLevel` in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf , maybe u should see if it's for 'error' enabled

Comment: Tried change to more verbose but 414 is still no present in the log. I've found solution to hide 414 but I want to show them https://www.debian-administration.org/article/119/Avoid_logging_overlong_Apache_requests